# How to Fill a text area on click of a link in asp.net core mvc using c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to fill some log output on the click of a link (which does some processing on the server side) in a text area.

Here is a Sample code :-

Controller :-

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var logOutput = "this is my output which goes into textarea."

        //some code maybe to populate the textarea

        return View();
    }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@model AspNetCoreMVC.Views.Shared.IndexModel

@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
}

@Html.ActionLink("FillTextArea","Index","Home")
<br /><br />
<textarea class="text-info" id="txtLog" style="width:1080px;height:200px"></textarea>
```

HTML View :-

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7Qac.jpg)

Could you please advise how can I make this happen. I am still new learner on asp.net core MVC.

Thanks

Shobhit

Comment: Did you try `viewbag` to fill out `textarea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

1. Using `ViewBag`

Inside `Controller Action Method`

```
ViewBag.LogOutput = "this is my output which goes into textarea.";
```

Inside `View`

```
<textarea class="text-info" id="txtLog" style="width:1080px;height:200px">@ViewBag.LogOutput</textarea>
```

2. Using `jQuery`
   Create `Ajax Call` on `Button Click`

Create `Button` inside `View`

```
<button id="FillTextArea">Fill Text Area</button>
```

Bottom of the view, make an ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#FillTextArea").on("click",function(){
        type: "GET",
        URL: "Home/GetLogOutput",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#txtLog').innerHtml(data.message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Create `GetLogOutput` action method inside controller

```
Public JsonResult GetLogOutput()
{
    string logoutput = "your log output";
    return Json(new { message = logoutput }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Method 1 worked perfect. I would also try the 2nd method as well as I want to learn different ways.

Comment: Good, kindly upvote the answer if it solves your problem.